# Wanted to create a system where i can create/delete and add activities to my catalog, would love someone to give my code some feedback C#

Tags: c#, list, constructor

Its not finished yet. I want to know if my constructor and list are correct and dry coding?
i want to create a system where i can add activities to my catalog
so for example footballgame, when it will end and start etc.

```
public class AktivitetsKatalog
   {
        public string AktivitetsNavn { get; set; }
        public string Lokation { get; set; }
        public List<Aktivitet> Aktiviteter { get; set; }


        public AktivitetsKatalog(string aktivitetsNavn, string lokation)
        {
            Lokation = lokation;
            AktivitetsNavn = aktivitetsNavn;
            Aktiviteter = new List<Aktivitet>();

        }

            AktivitetsKatalog katalog1 = new AktivitetsKatalog("boldspil", "vanløse");
            AktivitetsKatalog katalog2 = new AktivitetsKatalog("Basket", "Holbæk");
            Console.WriteLine(katalog1);
            Console.WriteLine(katalog2);

            
            katalog1.Aktiviteter.Add(new Aktivitet(1, 13, 18, new DateTime(2022, 08, 14), new DateTime(2022, 08, 21)));
            katalog2.Aktiviteter.Add(new Aktivitet(1, 13, 18, new DateTime(2022, 08, 15), new DateTime(2022, 08, 22)));
            
public class Aktivitet
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int MinAlder { get; set; }
       public int MaxAlder { get; set; }
       public DateTime StartTidspunkt { get; set; }
       public DateTime SlutTidspunkt { get; set; }


        public Aktivitet(int id, int minAlder, int maxAlder, DateTime startTidspunkt, DateTime slutTidspunkt)
        {
            Id = id;
            MinAlder = minAlder;
            MaxAlder = maxAlder;
            StartTidspunkt = startTidspunkt;
            SlutTidspunkt = slutTidspunkt; 
        }



            katalog1.PrintAktiviteter();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to in what *ways* it is "not finished yet"?

Comment: I think this question belongs to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, find it difficult to connect the catalog and the activity. Like the name of the activity together with the list? 
"boldspil", "vanløse" + the activity is not together when called.